# Can a microservice send async message to itself via a queue system like RabitMQ?

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, message-queue

I am experiencing a project where a microservice sends asynchronous message to itself via RabbitMQ, because it contains both the message producer and consumer parts. The reason is that the service can then produce the same type messages to the other services and receive the same type message from the other services.

This pattern is new to me. Is it anti-pattern in the microservice world?

Comment: It's definitely doable, but feels like a good recipe for an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the reason given is the best motivation, but a service sending messages to itself is perfectly normal in CQRS-style architectures. In such architectures, each service would host two processes: a front-end or public API (e.g. a web site or REST API) and a background process/daemon that handles all the messages that the public API puts on the queue.